# Partitioning of data in training and test set, keeping the right prevalence

Tags: r, dataframe, random, split, regression

I have a dataset with 100 variables and more than 3000 observations.

Many of these variables, are **factors**, where a level appears for example, just 3 or 4 times in all the observations of the dataset.

For example:

```
dat$Var_56
1
1
1
0 #the "0" level just happens 4 times on 3000 obs
1
1
..
```

This happens for many variables (levels are not 0 and 1, but, for example, the zone of the city). When I try to split the dataset in Training and Test set, and then I prepare the data using the function `model.matrix()` (that expands all the factors) what happens is that, basically, training and test set have different variables, and so it is impossible to check the validity of the estimated linear model.

What can we do in these situations?

Comment: In theory, you could do stratified random sampling, but I think the better approach is to reconsider what features go into your model. If there are 4, 0s  in dat$Var_56, then there is likely not enough variation to learn from that feature.

Comment: @AriAnisfeld consider that this one was a simplified example. If i have a factor with 7 levels, where the first 5 levels appear 100 times each, and then 2 levels that appear just 4 or 3 times each, what should i do with this feature? 
As regards stratified random sampling, I was also thinking about it but i think that this was a good idea if just a single variable was so unbalanced. Instead in my dataset, i have more than 15 variables very unbalanced

Comment: I would try making "other" categories or relabeling the factors into related groups that absorb the rare categories. This book chapter discusses related options: http://www.feat.engineering/encoding-predictors-with-many-categories.html